# Android: Кодировка в WebView

Tags: android, html, java, webview

Проблемка такая: есть готовый HTML-код (таблица в основном своём).
Я его записываю в переменную и вывожу через WebView. 
И фишка в том,что у меня текст нормальный, русский в эмуляторе и на смартфоне. А у друга крякозяблы - что-то с кодировкой не то.
В чём может быть проблема. Пробовал текст хранить и просто как переменная и в файле - одна малина.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadData(text,"text/html","utf-8");
```

Строка примерного плана:

```
<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>Не найдено.</body></html>
```

Comment: Какие аппараты? Какие версии андроид?

Comment: я стёр коммент, думал исправил в вопросе - может быть вы  кавычки забыли ?

    <meta charset='utf-8'>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Попробуй вот это :

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Это стопудово работает, сам когда-то с этим сталкивался и эта функция помогла.

Comment: действительно работает