# При передаче JSON WordPress REST API слетает кодировка

Tags: json, wordpress

Здравствуйте всем! Сайт на Вордпрессе и я через плагины WordPress REST API (Version 2) и REST API – Filter Fields передаю в андроид-приложение статьи с сайта... вроде все нормально... но когда открываю саму статью, то вижу вот это - как-будто кодировка слетела... помогите решить проблему...
все файлы проверял они в utf-8 без BOM

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот сам файл Post.java:

```
package com.wordpressappexample;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.Map;

public class Post extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView title;
    WebView content;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Gson gson;
    Map<String, Object> mapPost;
    Map<String, Object> mapTitle;
    Map<String, Object> mapContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post);

        final String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        content = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.content);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Post.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

        String url = "http://www.mysite.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/"+id+"?fields=title,content";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                gson = new Gson();
                mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(s, Map.class);
                mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                mapContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("content");

                title.setText(mapTitle.get("rendered").toString());
                content.loadData(mapContent.get("rendered").toString(),"text/html","UTF-8");

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Post.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Post.this);
        rQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить в файле wp-config.php строчку: 
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4')`; 
на 
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

А в самом приложении

```
content = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.content);
content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Сделал, но к сожалению ничего не изменилось... что же делать.. руки опускаются((((

Comment: Посмотреть на ваш json можно по урлу, чтобы исключить само ваше приложение для andoid, в чем я не силен

Comment: Вижу у вас только одно отличие по коду

`title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);` и `content = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.content);`. Попробуйте для теста `content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);`

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193390/android-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-webview) по WebView