# как вставить кириллицы в Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Я хочу в Android WebView вставить текст с английскими буквами, но у меня получается вот так:
[image]

код:

```
output.loadData( "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body>"+pr+"\n\n<br><br><br><br><b>-<a href=\""+csite+"\" >"+csite+"</a></b></body></html>","text/html","utf-8");
```

как это исправить?

спасибо!

Comment: Проблема вероятнее всего в кодировке. В HTML Вы указываете UTF-8. А, в какой кодировке сами выводимые данные?

Comment: там нормальныя кириллица и кодеровка utf-8. Все работает нормально с TextView и Html.fromhtml(pr); .

Comment: Тогда Вам возможно поможет вот [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193390/android-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-webview).

Comment: спосибо Стрелетз, типер все заработало

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Android: Кодировка в WebView](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193390/android-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-webview)